# Convert table subquery to active record equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to replicate the following SQL in Rails3 active record, nothing I've found so far comes close. So, any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT AVG(DAILY_AVG) FROM (
    SELECT user_code, (COUNT(actioned_at) / 200) as DAILY_AVG
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY user_code
) TMP
```

I'm currently executing this directly using ...connection.select_value(sql) but would really like to figure out the active record way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The inner query can be written as:

```
Transaction.group(:user_code).select("COUNT(actioned_at) / 200 AS daily_avg")
```

And then to nest this to get the average we can do:

```
Transaction.select("AVG(daily_avg)").from(Transaction.group(:user_code).select("COUNT(actioned_at) / 200 AS daily_avg"))[0].avg.to_f
```